# Prolog arrow operator

Tags: prolog, logic

```
| ?- true ; (true->false)
yes
| ?- (true->false) ; true.
no
| ?- false ; true.
yes
```

From what I understand the 'yes'/'no' result tells the user whether the query was successful or not. The query is always successful on the predicate `true` and it always fails on `false`.

1. since `;/2` means OR (which is commutative) the first two queries should be equivalent(both successful)
2. in predicative logic the formulas `(true->false)` and `false` evaluate to FALSE, so the last two queries should be equivalent

Therefore: the second query appears to be inconsistent with theoretical logic

Is there a mistake in my reasoning? I feel I'm not understanding something fundamental.

Answer (score 10):

This is a very good question.

Just to elaborate on @larsmans's answer, the `->/2` predicate acts as an `if-then-else` when combined with the `;/2` predicate. On it's own, it's just `if-then`.

Looking at the `if-then-else` construct, the description given in the [GNU Prolog manual says](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/html_node/gprolog023.html#sec67):

> `->/2` is often combined with `;/2` to define an `if-then-els`e as follows: `Goal1 -> Goal2 ; Goal3.` Note that `Goal1 -> Goal2` is **the first argument
>   of the (;)/2** and Goal3 (the else part) **is the second argument**. Such an
>   `if-then-else` control construct first **creates a choice-point for the
>   else-part** (intuitively associated with `;/2`) and then executes `Goal1`.
>   **In case of success [of `Goal1`], all choice-points created by `Goal1` together with
>   the choice-point for the else-part are removed** and Goal2 is executed.
>   If Goal1 fails then Goal3 is executed.

In this case we have:

```
(true -> false) ; true
```

The first `true` is `Goal1`, which succeeds. As soon as that happens, according to the description of the behavior of the predicate, the choice point that would lead you to the second `true` statement (`Goal3`) is REMOVED. So when the `false` is encountered, failure occurs with no backtracking to the second `true` and the entire query fails.

If, however, you did something like this:

```
foo :-
    true -> false.
foo :-
    true
```

There's a choice point after the first `foo` clause fails, so you get:

```
| ?- foo.
yes.
```

---

I think the confusion stems from comparing `false ; true` with `(true -> false) ; true`. A more analogous expression to `(true -> false) ; true` would be:

```
(true, !, false) ; true
```

Which will also evaluate to `false` because of how `;` works. The `;` provides a choice point in the event of failure of the first clause. But if the first clause has a cut and eliminates the choice point, then it won't be taken and the query fails overall.

Comment: Can't the expression be seen as `;(->(true, false), true)`? In this case, how is "choice-points [...] for the else-part are removed" possible, as '->/2' is an argument to ';/2', so it shouldn't be able to change its definition?

Comment: @octavian, actually it is consistent if you take the analogous example of `;((true,!,false),false)`. That query will come back `false` because, even though the first expression is `false`, the choice point has been eliminated with a cut. I added further explanation to my answer.

Comment: a rare - good and interesting - question indeed. :) I'll just add that it is natural to omit the false alternative ( `(true -> false; false) ; true.` ) and this Q shows that in Prolog we should be really careful about it.

Comment: @octavian is my answer satisfactory?

Answer (score 7):

The arrow in Prolog does not correspond to material implication in first-order logic. It's a ternary "if-then-else" operator with an optional alternative. Because of the way it's implemented in Prolog syntax,

```
(true -> false) ; true
```

does not mean what you think it does. It's parsed as `true -> false ; true`:

```
?- ((true -> false) ; true) =.. Expr.
Expr = [;, (true->false), true].

?- (true -> false ; true) =.. Expr.
Expr = [;, (true->false), true].
```

so it fails, because it means "if `true` then `false` else `true`", i.e. `false`.

Comment: Do you mean to say  "if `true` then `false` else `true`"  ?

Comment: @octavian: eh, yes. Fixed that.